# git change all history for committers names and email for specific committer

Tags: git, commit, git-filter-branch

How i cant change the name and email for all my commits history but for and specific commiter..

something like, foreach allcommits if committer_name = "Hugo Casa"
change :
 committer_name
committer_email
author_name
author_email

and after do this,
push and refresh the data of the history.

please helppp i search and found this:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "production251" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Hugo Casanova";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Hugo Casanova";
                GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="hugo.casanova.ibusplus.com";
                GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="hugo.casanova.ibusplus.com";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD


git filter-branch --env-filter '
    oldname="(old name)"
    oldemail="(old email)"
    newname="(new name)"
    newemail="(new email)"
    [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$oldemail" ] && GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$newemail"
    [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$oldemail" ] && GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$newemail"
    [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "$oldname" ] && GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$newname"
    [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "$oldname" ] && GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$newname"
    ' HEAD
```

but...after that :
write: git log --pretty=format:"%an" | sort -u
and the name of production251 show ..

i found new code:

git filter-branch --force --env-filter '
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = dmiguel" ];
then
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Diana Miguel";
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="paola.miguel@ibusplus.com";
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Diana Miguel";
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="paola.miguel@ibusplus.com";
fi' -- --all

this is well? or not? after put this code on terminal (ubuntu), need some code adittional?, push or something?

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the values you set for GIT_COMMITTER_NAME and the others between when you set them and when you execute `git commit-tree`.  You either need to make it all on the same command line or use `export` in front of them.